# How to detect duplicate Lists in Map<String,List<String>>

Tags: java, collections

I have a Map of the form `Map<String,List<String>>`.   The key is a document number, the List a list of terms that match some criteria and were found in the document.
In order to  detect duplicate documents I would like to know if any two of the `List<String>` have exactly the same elements (this includes duplicate values).
The `List<String>` is sorted so I can loop over the map and first check `List.size()`.  For any two lists
that are same size I would then have to compare the two lists with `List.equals()`.
The Map and associated lists will never be very large, so even though this brute force approach  will not  scale well it
will suffice.  But I was wondering if there is a better way.  A way that does not involve so much
explicit looping and a way that will not produce an combinatorial  explosion  if the Map and/or Lists get a lot larger.
In the end all I need is a yes/no answer to the question: are any of the lists identical?

Comment: You can't get better than `O(n)` for comparing two lists is equal or not. What do you want to do with the equal lists?

Comment: Rohit, I don't  want to  do anything with the Lists.  I just need a yes/no answer to the question: is there at least one duplicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the lists to a set data structure one by one. Happily the `add` method will tell you if an equal list is already present in the set:

```
HashSet<List<String>> set = new HashSet<List<String>>();
for (List<String> list : yourMap.values()) {
    if (!set.add(list)) {
        System.out.println("Found a duplicate!");
        break;
    }
}
```

This algorithm will find if there is a duplicate list in O(N) time, where N is the total number of characters in the lists of strings. This is quite a bit better than comparing every pair of lists, as for n lists there are n(n-1)/2 pairs to compare.

Comment: Joni, Great idea!  I'm going with this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Map.containsValue()`. Won't be more efficient than what you describe, but code will be cleaner. Link -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsValue%28java.lang.Object%29

Also, depending on WHY exactly you're doing this, might be worth looking into this interface -> http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a better way, but a cleaner way would be to create an object that implements Comparable and which holds one of your List.  You could implement hashcode() and equals() as you describe above and change your map to contain instances of this class instead of the Lists directly.

You could then use HashSet to efficiently discover which lists are equal.  Or you can add the values collection of the map to the HashSet and compare the size of the hashset to the size of the Map.

Answer (score 0):

From the JavaDoc of 'List.equals(Object o)':

> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns
>   true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists
>   have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two
>   lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal if (e1==null ?
>   e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).) In other words, two lists are defined to
>   be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. This
>   definition ensures that the equals method works properly across
>   different implementations of the List interface.

This leads me to believe that it is doing the same thing you are proposing: Check to make sure both sides are a List, then compare the sizes, then check each pair.  I wouldn't re-invent the wheel there.

You could use `hashCode()` instead, but the JavaDoc there seems to indicate it's looping as well:

> Returns the hash code value for this list. The hash code of a list is
>   defined to be the result of the following calculation:

```
 int hashCode = 1;
  Iterator<E> i = list.iterator();
  while (i.hasNext()) {
      E obj = i.next();
      hashCode = 31*hashCode + (obj==null ? 0 : obj.hashCode());
  }
```

So, I don't think you are saving any time.  You could, however, write a custom List that calculates the hash as items are put in.  Then you negate the cost of doing looping.

Comment: Using a hash code won't help you compare two lists for equality.  However, the _number_ of list equality comparisons looks like n(n-1)/2 if I understand the problem correctly, and a hash code (or `HashSet`) would certainly help speed that up.

Comment: The hashCode would not guarantee equality, but as it's coded it would show if two Lists are most likely equal since its base implementation takes all the entries as input to defining the Hash.  Therefore, you could test the hashcode of both against each other, then determine if you need to do further comparisons.  But, since they both seem to loop through once, I don't think your saving any instructions at all.